# Categorizing Data frame with R

Tags: r, dataframe, categories, percentage, categorical-data

I have a following sample code to make one data frame containing information for more than 1 ID.
I want to sort them by defined categories.
In which I want to see the percentage change at specific (given time for e.h here t=10) with respect to
its baseline value and return the value of that found category in output.
I have explained detailed step of my calculation below.

```
a=c(100,105,126,130,150,100,90,76,51,40)
t=c(0,5,10,20,30)
t=rep(t,2)
ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
data=data.frame(ID,t,a)
```

## My desired Calculation

```
 1)for all ID  at t=0 "a" value is baseline
 2) Computation
    e.g At Given t=10 (Have to provide) take corresponding a value
   %Change(answer) = (taken a value - baseline/baseline)
 3) Compare the answer in the following define CATEGORIES..
   #category
   1-If answer>0.25
   2-If -0.30<answer<0.25
   3-If -1.0<answer< -0.30
   4-If answer== -1.0
 4)Return the value of category
```

## Desired Output

```
 ID My_Answer
 1    1
 2    3
```

Can anybody help me in this.I do understand the flow of my computation but not awre of efficient way of doing it as i have so many ID in that data frame.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do math with columns than with rows.  So the first step is to move `baseline` numbers into their own columns, then use `cut` to define these groups:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

foo <- data %>%
  filter(t == 0) %>%
  left_join(data %>% 
              filter(t != 0),
             by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(percentchange = (a.y - a.x) / a.x,
         My_Answer = cut(percentchange, breaks = c(-1, -0.3, 0.25, Inf),
                         right = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE, labels = c("g3","g2","g1")),
         My_Answer = as.character(My_Answer),
         My_Answer = ifelse(percentchange == -1, "g4", My_Answer)) %>%
  select(ID, t = t.y, My_Answer)

foo 
  ID t.x a.x t.y a.y percentchange My_Answer
1  1   0 100   5 105          0.05        g2
2  1   0 100  10 126          0.26        g1
3  1   0 100  20 130          0.30        g1
4  1   0 100  30 150          0.50        g1
5  2   0 100   5  90         -0.10        g2
6  2   0 100  10  76         -0.24        g2
7  2   0 100  20  51         -0.49        g3
8  2   0 100  30  40         -0.60        g3
```

You can see that this lets us calculate `My_Answer` for all values at once.  if you want to find out the values for `t == 10`, you can just pull out those rows:

```
foo %>%
  filter(t == 10)

  ID  t My_Answer
1  1 10        g1
2  2 10        g2
```

Comment: Can you take off that %>% symbols and put regualr symbols so that i can understand in basic way how you program the code ?Thank you

Comment: Dear,I am using R.2.12.1 version and unfortunately i am unable to run above mentioned way.Though I did got your whole thoguht process.Can you please guide me in this.